# AJP and SSL communication to application server

Tags: java, apache, ssl, https, ajp

I have a client which access server through HTTPS. The server is a Java based web application running in WildFly application server.

Now I need to put a apache proxy between client and server and I need to set AJP (usually port 8009) to my application server or servers.

I assumed that if there is HTTPS then I wouldn't see clear text packet data through AJP. But I see everything when capturing data on server's AJP 8009 port.

How can AJP decapsulate SSL communication and see inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AJP protocol does not wrap HTTP or HTTPS. Apache is where HTTPS ends, and from Apache to Tomcat the data is sent over the AJP protocol.